# What does the hexadecimal number in a reference to an array, hash, etc. indicate?

Tags: perl, ref

When printing a reference to an array, hash, etc, what is that hexadecimal number in brackets?

```
perl -e 'print []'
```

Gives an output like: ARRAY(0x9acb830)

What is 0x9acb830 exactly? If I print the same ref again, this number changes.

Comment: When you say "print the same ref again" do you mean "run the same program again"?  There's no guarantee Perl will allocate the same memory from process to process.

Comment: @Schwern: I’d be surprised if it changed in a “trivial” program that does nothing but what he wrote above. There’s a diff tween running `perl -le 'print [ ] for 1..5'`, where the address *does* change, and running `repeat 5 perl -le 'print [ ]'`, where it does *not*. Again, that’s a trivial case, and your statement is too sensible to disagree with; larger programs have too many possible code paths to guarantee deterministic results at this level.

Comment: @tchrist On OS X repeated runs give the same number, but on Debian I get different numbers.  That's to be expected, `malloc()` is an unpredictable beastie and is chock full of the blackest magic.  In fact, I'm surprised it gets the same memory address from run to run on OSX.  But who knows what that number really represents in a modern operating system?

Comment: @Schwern, You might also be seeing address space layout randomization. Linux has an implementation for nearly all programs, OS X only uses it for a few libraries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you print the same ref again the number should remain the same; the number is the actual address of the SV header for the referred to thingy.

Comment: If "thingy" is the official Perl terminology, it explains a LOT about Perl ;))))

Comment: It only is for us old-school types.  Camel III replaced it with "referent".

Comment: "A thingy, as defined in Perl's own documentation, is anything a reference points to, such as an object. If you are an especially boring person, you could call it a referent instead." Intermediate Perl, second edition. I <3 Perl even more now : )

Comment: Re SLaks deleted answer "It's the object's memory address.", that is correct.  It is the same number that Scalar::Util::refaddr will return.

Comment: @ysth, Slaks: I stand corrected, then. Some minor checking confirms it, too: `C:\>perl -MScalar::Util=refaddr -E "$test = []; say q!Stringified ref: !, $test; say q!refaddr: !, refaddr($test); say q!manually: !, hex(substr $test, index($test, q!(!) + 1, -1)"`

Comment: @ysth: Jon and I argued that one pretty strongly for *Camel Ⅲ.* I always found it bothersome to use *thingy* or *thingies* in official discussions, but admit that the homophony of *referents* and *reference* is annoying. Mostly *thingy* just means *whatchamacallit* these days; that’s the use in latterday Camels. Running `ˋegrep -i 'thing(y|ies)' perl/pod/*.podˋ` turns up 4 hits in the standard src distro, in **perl{58delta,func,guts,obj}.pod**, to be precise. I recently resorted to *thingy* again, but now forget where.

Answer (score 1):

It's basically the memory location of the array. Perl is trying to let you know you're trying to print a reference and not a scalar value.

Try this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @foo = qw(one two three four five);
print @foo . "\n";   #Prints the array in a scalar context (five items)
print \@foo . "\n";
print $foo[1] . "\n";
print \$foo[1] . "\n";

5
two
SCALAR(0x100804ff0)
ARRAY(0x10082ae48)
```

Notice that when I print a reference, Perl tries to do the *right thing*. Instead of attempting to print some strange value, it tells you that you're trying to print a scalar or array reference.